# Issue with In-App-Purchases! Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

My problem is: I setted up an iAP in my app and when the user taps on a button it ask him "would you like to buy this". However, I have a image and a backround image placed on the button. I have this code implementet, that if the user hast bought the item the image of the button, which is a lock icon disappears. It works on the simulator fine, but on the device I am able to buy the item but the lock icon doesnt appears at all. Even if I havent bought the item theres no lock icon. On the simulator there's a lock item, if the item wasnt bought. I use the `BOOL` in my .h file: `-(BOOL)IAPItemPurchased;` and in the .m file I use the IAPItemPurchased to hide the foreground image, in my `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    if ([self IAPItemPurchased]) {
        [buy setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    } else {
        [buy setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Lock.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
}
```

Does have anyone suggestions or solutions what to do?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly Check the Image Name, because In Simulator the Name of image is **Case Insensitive**, but Device it is **case sensitive**.

**( or )**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
 [super viewDidLoad];

 if ([self IAPItemPurchased]) {
    [buy setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

} else {
    [buy setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Lock.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}}
```